# How can a query with ORDER BY run faster than the same query without ordering?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a SQL Server database with EventJournal table with the following columns:

```
Ordering (bigint, primary key)
PersistenceID (nvarchar(255))
SequenceNr (bigint)
Payload (varbinary(max))
```

Other columns are omitted for clarity. In addition to the primary key on Ordering there is a unique constraint on PersistenceID+SequenceNr.

If I run a query

```
select top 100 * from EventJournal where PersistenceID like 'msc:%'
```

... it takes very long time to execute (the table contains more than 100M rows)

But if I add ordering to results:

```
select top 100 * from EventJournal where PersistenceID like 'msc:%' order by Ordering
```

... then it returns the result immediately.

The execution plan for both queries are the same and in essence is the clustered index scan on PK. Then why does the first query take long time to execute?

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventJournal](
    [PersistenceID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNr] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Manifest] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Payload] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Tags] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Ordering] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SerializerId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventJournal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ordering] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [QU_EventJournal] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [PersistenceID] ASC,
    [SequenceNr] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

This it 1st plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ3kCo-Fv

And here's the 2nd one:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy1B0ibtP

Comment: Could you please paste both the ACTUAL plans by using https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and copy both the links here?

Comment: I think you should examine your plans in the section "PK scan". Your second plan probably has Ordered = True while the first can have it False, so they are different

Comment: I doubt that the 2 execution plans are identical.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, they are different. But he don't want to show them to us

Comment: I'd love to show you the plans! Working on it...

Comment: @sepupic Updated the post with plans.

Comment: As I wrote you already, the first scan is UNORDERED, but the second is ORDERED, so your plans are DIFFERENT

Comment: And I wonder why unordered scan is more expensive than the ordered one? Isn't query execution supposed to find the most efficient plan so not setting order constraint should free its hand to choose the ordered scan if it's faster?

Comment: Please paste the ACTUAL plans, your plans are estimated only, but you answered why the unordered scan was chosen in the first case: server also thought it would be faster to make an unordered scan :) In the second case it would not chose unordered scan since it means to add a sort, as there is order by in your query, so it was constrained to chose ordered and the plan happened to be better.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I had too much trust in server's ability to figure out what plan would be most efficient. I think I understand it better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, the plans are different, the difference is in access method:

The first plan uses unordered scan:

[image]

And the second plan uses ordered scan:

[image]

By the way, the other answer suggests useless `index`.

SQL Server will NOT use this `index`, as it's equivalent to the non-clustered `index` already in place. As the index `QU_EventJournal` `on ([PersistenceID], [SequenceNr])` was not used, the same way the index on `(PersistenceID, Ordering)` will not be used.
Both of these indexes has `PersistenceID`, `Ordering` in the index as `Ordering` is `clustered index key`, so it is presented in `index on ([PersistenceID], [SequenceNr])` even if you don't see it in the definition. The suggested index will be also bigger as it is not defined as `unique`, and the sizes of other fields are the same: `Ordering` is `bigint`, `SequenceNr` is `bigint`.

It's wrong to think that in index on 2 fields the second field(Ordering) can be used to avoid the sort in the second query, it's not true.

For example the index on `PersistenceID`, `Ordering` can have rows like these:

- msc:123, 100
- msc:124, 5
- msc:124, 6
- msc:125, 1

I hope you clearly see that the index is ordered by `PersistenceID`, `Ordering`,
but the result of the second query is expected to be

- msc:125, 1
- msc:124, 5
- msc:124, 6
- msc:123, 100

So the `SORT` operator is needed, so this index will not be used.

Now to your question:

> shouldn't lack of ORDER BY be used by the query analyzer as an
> opportunity to build more efficient execution plan without ordering
> constraints

Yes you are correct, without order by server is free to choose both the `ordered` and `unordered` scan, and yes you are right in this:

> I also don't understand why using TOP without ORDER BY is a bad
> practice in case I want ANY N rows from the result

When you don't need top N ordered by, because you just want to see what kind of records have 'msc:' in them, you should not add order by because it could cause a `SORT` in your plan.

And to your main question:

> Then why does the first query take long time to execute?

The answer is: **this was pure coincidence**.
Your data is laying in way that the rows with 'msc:' in them go first, in the order defined by Ordering. And if you scan your index not in order they are just in the middle or at the end of the table.

If you seek for another pattern in `PersistenceID` the `unordered scan` will be faster

Comment: Thanks a lot, very well explained.